# How to get rid of "Add to reading list"?

Tags: google-chrome, reading-list

Getting rid of Reading List feature in Google Chrome [was a piece of cake](https://www.howtogeek.com/719439/how-to-disable-and-remove-the-google-chrome-reading-list/). But, how to get rid of this nasty and annoying little thing:

[image]

I am using two PC, "old" and "new" one. I have this pesky little thing only on "new" one. Clicking "star" on old's Google Chrome always opens up "Add bookmark" window directly. How to force the same behaviour on my new PC?

Comment: I was about to post it as an answer - but that same [page](https://www.howtogeek.com/719439/how-to-disable-and-remove-the-google-chrome-reading-list/#:~:text=Remove%20the%20Reading%20List%20in%20Chrome%2089%20and%20Older) you found have the answer. 
On the Chrome URL bar --> chrome://flags <-- Search for reading and disable it. You actually found the answer - just scroll down further on that same page.

Comment: @Darius Sorry for not reading entirely. Yes, you are right -- the answer is already there. I would still suggest you to add some answer here (with some brief description, not just URL). Because this site is visited by millions and may be a good source of information, while comments tends to be omit. It would also be my pleasure to accept your answer and bring you some rep. Thank you.